How to use a function that return refcursor in mapping in informatica powercenter
hello i have a function that return sys_refcursor
and i use this function inside a stored procedure as a parmater i tried to import the function as stored procedure transformation in the map but the problem is the return port doesn't exist in the transformation as the return value datatype is sys_refcursor i assume that informatica cannot translate it so how can i pass this function as a parameter in a procedure in powercenter map
P_Proc_Syntax('X', 'Y',1 ,10,Fun_x('CUSTOMER'),Fun_y('CUSTOMER'));

note fun_x and fun_y are functions that return sys_refcursor

I'm afraid it might not be possible and a rework may be needed to do this using PowerCenter way of coding. Please note PowerCenter is not 1:1 equivalent to SQL and should not be used in such way. Most commonly for example the cursors should be avoided and reworked to pipelines.
